# jquery load() on each() function working all together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

i am working around an ajax loading powered website . Here i am trying to load different url on different link but there is a little bit problem i am facing . There is used 4 links and 4 pages to load each page is linked with another but on clicking a link 4 pages are loading .

### my html is

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <a href="ajax/portfolio_single.php" data-content="ajax" class="ajax-call">this is one</a>
    <a href="ajax/portfolio_single2.php" data-content="ajax" class="ajax-call">hello</a>
    <a href="ajax/portfolio_single3.php" data-content="ajax" class="ajax-call">hello</a>
    <a href="ajax/portfolio_single4.php" data-content="ajax" class="ajax-call">hello</a>
    <div class="ajaxshow"></div>
</div>
```

### and my javascripts are

```
(function($){

'use strict';

var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
    pathname = window.location.pathname,
    url = window.location.href,
    ajaxUrl;

ajaxcontent.each( function(index, el) {

    $( this ).append('<span class="ajax-live"></span>');

    ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $( '.ajax-live' ).addClass('ajax-live-on');
        $( this ).after('<span class="ajax-close animated bounceInRight"></span>');
        $('.ajaxshow').append().load(ajaxUrl);
        $('.ajaxshow').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
        $('.ajaxshow').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $(document.body).on('click', '.ajax-close', function( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        $( '.ajax-live' ).removeClass('ajax-live-on');
        $( this ).removeClass('ajax-close');
        $( '.ajaxshow' ).fadeOut(600).slideUp();
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

though hete each function is not working it doesnot working.can anyone help?

A working example is here
http://orlandojoes.co.uk/website/ajaxTest.php

Answer (score 0):

user your code in document ready function like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
        pathname = window.location.pathname,
        url = window.location.href,
        ajaxUrl;

    ajaxcontent.each( function(index, el) {

        $( this ).append('<span class="ajax-live"></span>');

    });
$(document).off('click','[data-content="ajax"]');
$(document).on('click','[data-content="ajax"]',function(event) {
  var    ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            event.preventDefault();
            $( '.ajax-live' ).addClass('ajax-live-on');
            $( this ).after('<span class="ajax-close animated bounceInRight"></span>');
            $('.ajaxshow').append().load(ajaxUrl);
            $('.ajaxshow').addClass('animated bounceInUp');
            $('.ajaxshow').css('display', 'block');
        });
     $(document.body).off('click', '.ajax-close');
        $(document.body).on('click', '.ajax-close', function( event ){
            event.preventDefault();
            $( '.ajax-live' ).removeClass('ajax-live-on');
            $( this ).removeClass('ajax-close');
            $( '.ajaxshow' ).fadeOut(600).slideUp();
        });
    });
```

I hope this code will work.

Comment: your function is call in ready function of document.  Suppose when you  called javascript function and that time html element is not available in dom than your function will not work that's why you should call your function on ready function.

Comment: yah i know that.but problem is not there . THe problem is there is created 4 instances while there is used each.But when i click every dom element is created 4 times

Comment: Hey I edited my answer according to your problem . Please check and let me know that this answer helps you or not.

Comment: its not working yet . It comes the expected on but if i click on close button there comes the fourth one . I am uploading the demo content plz wait a while

Comment: just use   $('this').prev().find('.ajax-live').removeClass('ajax-live-on'); (OR JUST TRAVERSE WITH $(this) FOR BOTH CLASS "ajax-live" AND "ajaxshow" THEN PERFORM ACTION ). I just gave on demo code. I hope if traverse correctly then you achive your goal.   And If you suttisfy then upvote my answer

Comment: Hi take a look at here . http://orlandojoes.co.uk/website/ajaxTest.php .. when you will click it produces 4 rounded blue object at once . But it should create one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77525/discussion-between-sumit-jha-and-muhaimin).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `ajaxUrl` variable is within a different closure than the one you assume so by the time it is clicked, it is always the fourth link.

This is because first you do

```
var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
    pathname = window.location.pathname,
    url = window.location.href,
    ajaxUrl;
```

Here, `ajaxUrl` is global to the 'each' closure. In order to fix this problem, remove the `ajaxUrl` declaration from outside the 'each' scope, and define it within

```
var ajaxcontent = $('[data-content="ajax"]'),
    pathname = window.location.pathname,
    url = window.location.href;

ajaxcontent.each( function(index, el) {

    $( this ).append('<span class="ajax-live"></span>');

    var ajaxUrl = $(this).attr('href');

    $(this).click(function(event) {
.
.
.
```

Also change

```
$('.ajaxshow').append().load(ajaxUrl);
```

to

```
$('.ajaxshow').load(ajaxUrl);
```

There is no need for `append` as `load` will insert the HTML response within the `ajaxshow` div